# How to create a constant inside R package?

Tags: r, package, constants, environment

How to create the constant variable inside the R package, the value of which cannot be changed? In other words, how can we lock the pair name-value in package environment?

Example: In my package I am using a quantile of Normal distribution in loops of different functions, and do not want to calculate (or create) it all the time.

I tried `k_q3 <- qnorm(1 - 0.01/2); lockBinding("k_q3", environment())`, but it does not work.

UPDATE: The method above actually is workable. One cannot change the k_q3 neither inside package, not outside.

Comment: Did you get an error? I tried your method and chaning the variable, got this: `Error: cannot change value of locked binding for 'k_q3'`

Comment: Nope. I also exported this variable to NAMESPACE, and whenever I try to change it through `mypackagename::k_q1 <- 2` I got the following `Error in mypackagename::k_q1 <- 2 : object 'mypackagename' not found`

Comment: Actually it's working :) I add a function, which tries to change the value of `k_q1`, but it fails. Here is the code:  `#' @export
mmm <- function(x) {
    k_q1 <- x
}`

Comment: When building a package, you can use the command `devtools::use_data(constants, pkg, internal = TRUE)`, to save the variable `constants`, while ensuring it's not available to the package users. The function `use_data` supports saving multiple constants its first argument, `...`. More information can be found [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html).

Comment: I think the `R6` class which have private variables can act similar to constant to user of the package though internal code of the package can still modify the private variables.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and cleanest way would be to create a function, e.g.

```
K_Q3 <- function() { qnorm(1 - 0.01/2) }
```

Note that calling functions in R has a non-negligible overhead.
You should avoid calling it in loops, or copy it to a local variable before.

Answer (score 1):

Just like you create function objects for your package by placing a .R file that defines them in the "R" folder within your package directory. You can simply assign a numeric value `2.575829` to a variable name--just don't export it.